# remove words which consist 3 character using php

Tags: php, words

Please somebody help me.

I want to remove words which consist of 3 characters or less using php code, please help with the following sentence:

`$string = "this is my new minimalist style"`

The the result must be "this new minimalist style"

So what code that I should use to made that?

Comment: Isn't th word "new" 3 chars long?

Comment: He wants to remove *less* than 3 chars

Comment: @core1024: Yes, but it says the requirement is to remove characters less than three characters.

Comment: Now I see in the description he says "less than 3". I was confused by the caption, which I understand as "exactly 3".

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$string = "this is my new minimalist style"
$string = preg_replace(array('/\b\w{1,2}\b/','/\s+/'),array('',' '),$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
$text = "this is my new minimalist style";
$text = preg_replace("/\b(\w{1,2}\s|\s\w{1,2})\b/","", $text);
```

Comment: thanx for all...finally i try this code a its woork     $string = "this is my new minimalist style";
$no_char= array('is','my');
$pattern = '/\b(?:' . join('|', $no_char) . ')\b/i';
$output = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);

Answer (score 0):

Another soution for PHP >= 5.3 (also works with older versions, you'll just need to avoid anonymous function use):

```
$string = "this is my new minimalist style";

print implode(" ", array_filter(explode(" ", $string), function($item) { return strlen($item) >= 3; }));
```